# how to capitalize first letter of translated v-date-picker in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to know if there is any way to **capitalize** internalization of `v-date-picker`. I have managed to translate the days of week and months in `v-date-picker` in `vuetify` but I need to **make the first letter capital**. Any help would be appriciated.
What I have made so far:

```
<v-date-picker :locale="translateDate"
        v-model="date"
        :max="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
        @input="getDate"  />

...

translateDate() {
   let lang = this.$i18n.locale = this.$cookies.get('language')
   return lang
}
```

I have also this functions to capitalize that I can use:

```js
capitalize(str) {
   return capitalizeFirstLetter(str);
}

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
   return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using pure css. Take a loot at [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform):

```css
.v-date-picker-title__date,
.v-date-picker-header__value button {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```